# Apache Configuration

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, apache-2.4, https, httpd.conf

I am sure you may have encountered this issue.
I have a server with jira, bitbucket and confluence configured on the same server. As the bitbucket is moved to linux serer i am wondering how can I configure https://localhost.testdoain.corp/bitbucket2 to point to https://server02.testdomain.corp/bitbucket and load the application from that serer. For that I have tried below configuration on the httpd-ssl.conf. Which doesn't work. Any advise on this to make it work properly.
It takes me to the server but displays the page with a Oops can't find that or Oops you have found a dead link!

```
Listen 443

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLHonorCipherOrder on 
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost.corp
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/serviceinfo/"
ServerName www.localhost.corp:80
ServerAdmin joe.bloggs@localhost.corp
ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost _default_:443>

RedirectMatch ^/$ https://localhost.corp/jira


ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia Off
ProxyTimeout 12000

<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /synchrony http://localhost:8091/synchrony
<Location /synchrony>
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8091%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
</Location>

ProxyPass /jira http://localhost:8081/jira
ProxyPassReverse /jira http://localhost:8081/jira

ProxyPass /confluence http://localhost:8090/confluence
ProxyPassReverse /confluence http://localhost:8090/confluence

ProxyPass /bitbucket https://server02.testdomain.corp:8443/bitbucket/
ProxyPassReverse /bitbucket https://server02.testdomain.corp:8443/bitbucket/

#ProxyPass /bitbucket http://localhost:7990/bitbucket
#ProxyPassReverse /bitbucket http://localhost:7990/bitbucket

ProxyPass /rm http://localhost:3060/rm
ProxyPassReverse /rm http://localhost:3060/rm


SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine On

SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server.key"


<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
 SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
      "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>`
```

Not sure where to look for logs

Comment: *It doesn't work* is not a terribly descriptive error. What happens? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Thank you! I can see a page with some context from the server but it says Oops found dead link. where as if i  access the server  directly over url - https://server02.testdomain.corp:8443/bitbucket/ 
the application is working.

it is a kind of url re-direction i guess

Comment: Please check for jira logs and share error message, you can find logs inside jira installation directory `{JIRA_dir}/logs/catalina. out` or `{JIRA_dir}/home/log/atlassian-jira. log`.